# How to disable jQuery(document).ready(function()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to disable jQuery(document).ready(function() after jQuery(document).ajaxComplete.. 
This is my code.

```
function doStuff(){
  jQuery('.type-title').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
      if(!jQuery(this).parent('.type-top').hasClass('collapsed')){
        jQuery(this).parent('.type-top').addClass('collapsed');  
       }      
    };

jQuery(document).ready(doStuff);
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(doStuff);
```

Everything works fine, but after new div is open by ajax, Click function works only on new div, on old divs click does not work, it means I should disable jQuery(document).ready function. I have treid many things but no one was working.

how can I disable jQuery(document).ready function?
I try this, but it does not work too.

```
var flag = ' ';
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 flag = true;
   if(flag){ 
    doStuff();
   } 
}); 
jQuery.ajax({ 
  success: function(){
   flag = false;   
   doStuff(); 
   } 
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, and I suspect you're asking it based on some misunderstandings or false assumptions on your part.  Though one thing to note is that your selector looks wrong here: `jQuery('type-title')`

Comment: Why do you have the same callback to `.ready()` and `.ajaxComplete()`? Are you just trying to bind to all new `.type-title` elements?  (Assuming you're missing the period for a class, above)

Comment: Thanks , David , I fixed it.                  
I want this function works on new and old divs . But now it works or or .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching your event handler to the divs each time what you really need to do is use a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You didn't show your HTML so I will use an example, given,

```
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="type-top">
     <div class="type-title">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="type-top">
     <div class="type-title">...</div>
     <div class="type-title">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can listen to events on all the children by specifying a delegated listener,

```
function doStuff(){
 jQuery(".my-container").on("click", ".type-title", function() {
   e.preventDefault();
   if(!jQuery(this).parent('.type-top').hasClass('collapsed')){
     jQuery(this).parent('.type-top').addClass('collapsed');  
   }  
 });
}

jQuery(document).ready(doStuff);
```

This listener will automatically pick up events from new `.type-title` divs as they are added, so you only need to call this once when the document loads.

Comment: it works ) I tried it before , but for your example I understand that in JQ parent (.my-container) should be constant one, not "addable" element